# How can I call child component setState from parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 stateful class-based components nested within my main app, a parent class-based component. From child component 1, I've successfully called a parent callback method. From within that parent callback I want to call a method of child component 2, so I can setState of #2 without re-rendering the parent component. I've seen that many devs make the children stateless or even just omit them. However, React encourages devs to "componenatize" ... pointers plz!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First, try to share your code, is really hard to understand your problem without that, second, you're trying to communicate components calling callbacks methods of a parent? Looks like something where redux can help you.

Comment: You could pass a reference to the function to the parent component, but... that starts to get messy very quickly.

Comment: I found this online https://www.javascriptstuff.com/component-communication/#2-instance-methods I'm digging into it right now. Migual, I've seen mentions of redux and flux too, first gonna see if I can do it without. Dave, maybe I should keep it simple I'm just starting to get a little deeper with React

Answer (score 4):

if that's the case then you shoud consider lifting the state up to the parent: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

your child component should only then call parent methods to update the state, that way, you will have a unidirectional flow of data as what a react app should be. Basically, it encourages you to have a single source of truth and ensure synchronisation of data across your app. Besides it removes unnecessary logic like what you are doing right now:
[What does the "single source of truth" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182888/what-does-the-single-source-of-truth-mean)

Comment: Nice explaination  @Lelouch

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data in the parent's state and then allowing both children to update it via setStates wouldn't violate the concept of "componentizing" as long as the two children have narrowly declared inputs. If one child needs to update data inside another child, you can jump up a context level and store it in the parent- then an update of the data from either child will trigger a render of both children ensuring the display stays synchronized with the data while keeping the data in a single place (with the parent instead of split between the children).

Comment: Yeah, I can wrap my noggin around this concept ... guess I'm looking for a way to only trigger a re-render of 1 child component. Starting to think that React handles all of that though, and that a re-render of the parent is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Bingo, yes I can use a "React ref" to call an instance method of a child component. A ref is an attribute on a component instance. So, right now my child component uses its componentDidUpdate to call a callback in my parent, and the parent callback then uses refs to call an "update" method of specific child components. These update methods setState on child component and voila.

Comment: You can do this but there are better more predictable ways, like lifting state.

Answer (score 0):

So a colleague explained that calling setState in my main app actually will call setState on all children components (related by JSX expressions). Even though I liked the idea of nesting my event handlers within their relevant child components, it seems that the best practice pattern is to have all handlers in the main app, setState in the main app, then let React do its thing

Comment: And child components can have handlers but they'd be about UI behavior, not about data/state