# access function between two components react js

Tags: reactjs

I need to access Purchase Order component function, from another component.
This is my PurchaseOrder .js function

```
    const loadselectedValue = (value) => {
    setFieldValue('purchaseOrderNumber', value);
    setFieldValue('vendorName', dataObj.vendorName);
    setFieldValue('vendorSiteCode', dataObj.vendorSiteCode);
    setFieldValue('term', dataObj.term);
    setFieldValue('termDate', dataObj.termDate);
    setFieldValue('typelookup', dataObj.type);
    setFieldValue('vendorNo', dataObj.vendorNumber);

  };
```

This is my Invoice.js file.

```
    import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
    import PurchaseOrder from "components/createinvoice/PurchaseOrder";
    function Invoice() {
    
      useEffect(() => {
 // I need to call, loadselectedValue();
  }, []);

    }
```

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks

Comment: what kind of relation the two components have ?

Comment: you want to export the loadselectedValue first and ten import it {  loadselectedValue } in your Invoice.js

Comment: are these two component in same hierarchy or not ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182888/what-does-the-single-source-of-truth-mean
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html