# React Native Async storage is not in sync with the UI? How can I change this behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, android-asynctask

Hi There is a toggle in my component which will show a login method according to the value `true or false`

The login icon will show if true and will not if false.

The operation is carried out in the setting page.

So I make a toggle button In the setting page. I am using async storage since I wanna save data if the button opened by user or not.

Here what in the setting page

```
const toggleSwitch = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('enableBiometric', isEnabled.toString());
        setIsEnabled(!isEnabled);
};

const printSomething = async () => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('enableBiometric');
            console.log(value);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

return (
         <View>
             <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text>Turn on Biometric Login</Text>
                    <Switch
                        trackColor={{false: switchDefaultColor, true: primaryColor}}
                        thumbColor={isEnabled ? '#ffffff' : '#f4f3f4'}
                        ios_backgroundColor={switchDefaultColor}
                        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                        value={isEnabled}
                    />
                </View>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => printSomething()}>
                <Text>Text</Text>
                {isEnabled ? <Text>Enabled</Text> : <Text>DisEnabled</Text>}
            </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
)
```

What happens is the when the component is loaded the previous state of button state is loaded from the async storage.

But During the first 2 or 3 times of toggling switch. Only The Ui Change of  `<Text>Enabled</Text> or <Text>DisEnabled</Text>`. The Storage data won't change.

Eg Scenario

When component load, app get data from storage. The switch is `on`. When I press printSomething button its will say `on`.

When I press switch for the first time. The switch UI will go off. But when I press printSomething button its will still `on`.

Its always happen.

Comment: try this one https://snack.expo.dev/@hashtd/cranky-milkshake

Comment: @TusharD Its works , Thanks. But it will be very helpful why its works. Can you explain a little for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `enableBiometric` is needs to be loaded from `AsyncStorage` first after that render ui
- in `toggleSwitch` function, `isEnabled` value needs to be same for both `setIsEnabled` & `AsyncStorage.setItem`

> FYI: [What does the "single source of truth" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182888/what-does-the-single-source-of-truth-mean)

> https://snack.expo.dev/@hashtd/cranky-milkshake